# How to substitute an abstract class with an interface in Java?

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

I have an abstract class `Work` with two abstract methods (`init` and `work`) and one concrete method (`run`) working with the abstract methods.

```
class work
{
    abstract static class Work<T> implements Runnable
    {
        T data;

        abstract protected void init ();
        abstract protected void work ();

        public void run ()
        {
            init();
            work();
            System.out.println (data);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Runnable hello = new Work<String>() {
            protected void init () { data = "Hello $1!"; }
            protected void work () { data = data.replace ("$1", "World"); }
        };

        (new Thread(hello)).start();
    }
}
```

In order to get rid of the multiple inheritance problem I would like to convert the abstract class into an interface. But in Java interfaces can not contain a body. So where do I have to put the generic data and method after converting the abstract class into an interface?

I fear that it is not possible to get rid of the multiple inheritance problem as long as I want to share anything concrete. Is this right?

Comment: Where and how are you experiencing multiple inheritance problem here?

Comment: I fear this is not possible, one alternative to multiple inheritance is encapulation, where the "child" class stops extending the parent class and starts having an instance of the "parent" class as a field and then uses its methods. Whether this is appropriate depends heavily on your usage case though

Comment: It may help if you show the other parent class that the child class wants to extend and how the child would use both parents

Comment: @RohitJain The other parent might be some kind of application class `hello` likes to use or a test case class or anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

1. Create the `Work` interface
2. Create the `AbstractWork` class which is the abtract class implementing `Work` and containing the generic code
3. Create your implementation classes extending `AbstractWork`

That is exactly what is used in the JDK with `List` (the interface), `AbtractList` (the abstract class implementing `List`) and `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` (the implementation classes extending `AbstractList`).

Comment: What is the reason to have both List and AbstractList? It is possible to mark anything which is in AbstractList but not in List as `protected`. What is the difference between a protected AbstractList and the interface List?

Comment: Abstract contains the generic code used by many implementions of List. Yet, there also exists List implementation which do not extends AbstractList and thus do not use at all the generic code contained in the abstract class. The interface defines the contract while the abstract class contains shared code.

Comment: First this means that it is a stupid idea to replace an abstract class with an interface, because it is not possible. And second it is a stupid idea to think by this it might be possible to get rid of the inheritance problem, because there is no way around it. This reminds my of the fact that Java bugs me.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to separate the interface from the functionality; something like this:

```
public interface Work<T> {
    void init();
    T work();
}

public class Worker<T> implements Runnable {

    private final Work<T> work;

    Worker(Work<T> work) {
        this.work = work;
    }

    public void run () {
        work.init();
        T data = work.work();
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Runnable hello = new Worker<String>(new Work<String>() {
        private String data;
        public void init () { data = "Hello $1!"; }
        public String work () { return data.replace ("$1", "World"); }
    });

    (new Thread(hello)).start();
}
```

Comment: This does not change much. `hello` is still a `Worker` and I can not inherit it from something else.